# I am in a Laravel project. I created a PagesController at Http/Controller. I was trying to create a link between this page and routes/web.php

Tags: php, laravel, http, controller

I set up a new project and everything is running properly but I am having this problem. At web.php, there is an error message: Auth::routes is highlighted. Error - Undefined type 'Auth'.  I followed the commands to create a PagesController at Controller and it was successfully done.  At PagesController, I keyed in a function: public function index({ return 'INDEX';                                                                                                     At web.php, I key in **Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');** to link to PagesController as in the page attached.  However,when I run the bro[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M40KO.png)wser, it says that **PagesController does not exist.**  Can please help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... are you using Laravel 8?

Answer (score 0):

**The way, controllers are referenced from routes/web.php has changed from 7.0 to 8.0**

Assuming that you created your controller with

```
php artisan make:controller PagesController
```

and added

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PagesController;
```

your route in web.php would be in laravel 7:

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
```

according to https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers

but in laravel 8:

```
Route::get('/', [PagesController::class, 'index']);
```

as stated in https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers